# How can I get my public IPV4 address from NAT internal network with python

Tags: python, public, nat, ipv4

guys
I just want to look up my public ipv4 address from NAT internal network, I know lots of webpages offering that function, only if you visit them by opening webpages with a browser. The thing I figure out is to extract the IP address information from the webpage with python, I had used python's lib called 'requests', but every time the code response without IP information I anticipate when I visit those webpages which can show my public address correctly in a browser. I guess it is probably because those pages used a code-proof visiting strategy. So is there any way that I can use to get my public IP address with python code, just something like restful service?

Comment: https://api.ipify.org?format=json

Comment: You just need to pick better websites. E.g., the above comment, or `http://icanhazip.com` (and probably many others).

Comment: http://httpbin.org/ip

Answer (score 0):

```py
public_ip = requests.get('https://ifconfig.me').text
```

The simplest way to get your public IP is to get it from a REST service, like [ifconfig.me](https://ifconfig.me/), using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) (which you mentioned in your question and needs to be installed with pip). `requests.get()` sends an HTTP GET request to the REST API and returns a `Response` object that has a `text` attribute which contains the content of the response, in this case your public IP address.

Comment: Could you please write a few lines of explaining text as well?